# Putting a dropdown panel in the navbar Bootstrap 3.0.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to put a panel with a few form elements and a dropdown category selection into a collapsible navbar in bootstrap. Currently I have

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="z-index:5;">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img class="headerToolbarIcon2" src="img/configuration.png"> Configuration<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <form class="dropdown-menu" style="width:425%; padding-top:1px;">
                    <li>
                        <div class="container" id="configurationPanel" style="height:140px;">
                            <div class="panel-body panel-default" style="float:left;">
                                <p><strong> Article <br/> Properties:</strong></p>
                            </div>
                                <div class="panel-body panel-default" style="float:left; margin-left:20px;" >
                                <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black;"><strong>Category</strong></p>
                                <div class="btn-group">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data>
                                        Personal <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Weather</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Military</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Uncategorized</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </form>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I stopped event propagation on the panel, and the radio buttons work great, but whenever I click the "Personal" button to select from categories, the panel shuts. I'm sure it has something to do with having the data target of the parent dropdown, but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 3.0.3 can't show 2 dropdown-menu class with data-toggle="dropdown" because first click show class="dropdown-menu" and second click hide first class="dropdown-menu" and show the second . this your problem .

try this solution :

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="z-index:5;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a id="dp1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" ><img class="headerToolbarIcon2" src="vbnet.PNG" width="20px" height="20px"> Configuration<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <form class="dropdown-menu" style="width:425%; padding-top:1px;">
                        <li>
                            <div class="container" id="configurationPanel" style="height:140px;">
                                <div class="panel-body panel-default" style="float:left;">
                                    <p><strong> Article <br/> Properties:</strong></p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body panel-default" style="float:left; margin-left:20px;" >
                                    <p style="border-bottom:1px solid black;"><strong>Category</strong></p>
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <button id="dp2" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                            Personal <span class="caret"></span>
                                        </button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                            <li><a href="#">Weather</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Military</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">International</a></li>
                                            <li class="divider"></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Uncategorized</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("#dp2").click(function(){
                    $("#dp1").attr("data-toggle","");
                    $("#dp1").one("click",function(){
                        $("#dp1").attr("data-toggle","dropdown");
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: No luck. Menu still closes parent menu on clicking #dp2.

Comment: this code work for me, parent menu will close only if you click in #dp1.